# how is it possible for a crypto library to determine if you are using the right key to decrypt the message?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have used rsa to encrypt a small message using  my public key-e(corresponding private key-d). But if I decrypt it with another private key d', it gives a `bad padding exception`.
How  does it know that I have used the wrong key?

Comment: Every key will 'decrypt' a message, but only the right RIGHT key will produce the original input. A lot of libraries will embed a known-signature into the plaintext. If you decrypt the cyphertext and get the known-signature, it's fairly certain that you used the right key.

Comment: @MarcB : Does java's library do the samething.

Comment: "A lot of libraries will embed a known-signature into the plaintext" - really? Name one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RSA libraries would default to [PKCS#1 block type 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313) padding for public key encryption. In that case the data is must be at least 11 bytes less than the modulus size, and the plaintext is padded like:

00 02 r<sub>1</sub> r<sub>2</sub> r<sub>3</sub> r<sub>4</sub> ... r<sub>M</sub> ... 00 [your plaintext bytes]

where M >= 8 and r<sub>i</sub> are random positive bytes: they are all non-zero.

This is the actual value that raised to the e<sup>th</sup> power mod the modulus. So upon decryption the decryptor can check that the result looks this, i.e.

1. The high order byte is 0
2. The next to the high order byte is 2
3. At least the next 8 bytes are non-zero
4. A zero byte occurs somewhere after this

Comment: So this also ensures that the same message can have different ciphertexts with the same key(the random part ensures that) right? but the answers given above don't talk any thing about random bytes.

Comment: Now you say that in PKCS#1 block type 2 padding 11 bytes are appended before the plain text. But what if the plaintext in very small. Then even the 11 bytes appended will not be able to make m^e greater that the modulus N.(The purpose of adding padding is also to ensure that when you do m^e the resulting value will be greater than the modulus N. then you can do mod N). otherwise the attacker can just take the eth root of the cipher text and get the plain text

Comment: *at least 8* bytes of random (plus the other 3 bytes) are appended. Thats what the >= 8 means. If more are needed then more are appended. Or rather prepended.

Comment: sorry did not see the atleast. GOT IT!

Answer (score 3):

Using a padding scheme does give a decryptor a good idea that he is either using the wrong key or is dealing with corrupt data.

Padding schemes have a well-defined set of final bytes of plaintext.  If you are decrypting with the wrong key, your resulting "plaintext" is basically random garbage and therefore overwhelmingly unlikely to end in a valid padding sequence.

Comment: MarcB says that a known signature is embedded into the plaintext. So is it the signature or the padding scheme that is used to find out whether the decryption was using the correct key? One more doubt I have is that, I thought padding added a random sequesnce of bytes to the plain text, so that two ciphertext's of the same plaint text will not be the same. If it was a deterministic sequesnce then the same plaintexts will have the same ciphertexts.

Comment: No.  MarcB said that some libraries choose to do that.  Many don't and if you're directly using the java crypto functions it's probably not going to happen unless you write code to do it.

Comment: As for padding it's generally not random.  The purpose of padding is to pad the plaintext to a multiple of the cipher block size.  If you used random padding, when the message was decrypted, the receiver wouldn't know when the plaintext ended and the padding started.  So the padding is generally structured.  For example, with the popular PKCS#5 padding scheme if 5 bytes of padding are needed, each padding byte has the value 5.  So the decryptor can go to the end of the raw plaintext, see that the final byte is 5, then make sure the previous 4 bytes are also 5, then strip them all away.

Comment: If you want indentical plaintext encrypted with indentical keys to have different ciphertext, that's what a salt or initialization vector is for.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism is actually as simple as it is clever.

Imagine a block cipher that encrypts blocks of exactly 8 bytes: it divides each plaintext message into groups of 8 bytes and encrypts each group as a single block.  When it comes to the last block, there are two possibilities:

1. The block is shorter than 8 bytes and must be padded to exactly 8 bytes.  In this case, some number of bytes, *n*, must be appended to the block.  Each of those bytes has the same binary value of *n*.  So the last block will look like one of these, where `d` is a byte of data:

   > d d d d d d d 1
   >      d d d d d d 2 2
   >      d d d d d 3 3 3
   >      . . .
   >      d 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
2. The block is exactly 8 bytes long.  In this case, an *entire* block is appended to the message, so the last 2 blocks would look like this:

   > d d d d d d d d   8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8

Now, when the message is decrypted, the decryptor can tell unambiguously how many bytes of padding to remove.  And if the final block does not end with `n` characters, each with the binary value `n`, it knows the message has either been corrupted or decrypted with the wrong key.

---

Don't confuse this padding with the initialization vector, or IV, that is used to modify the *beginning* of the message.  The purpose of padding is to ensure the message contains only complete blocks, and to allow the decryptor to validate the key.  The IV is a random sequence of bytes that ensures the same plaintext can be encrypted many times with the same key, but still generate a different ciphertext each time.

Comment: But the answer given by GregS says that some random non zero bytes are also appended at the beginning of the plaintext according to PKCS#1 block type 2 padding.

Comment: This answer addresses symmetric block cipher padding, not RSA.